# EEA family permit for non-EEA family members

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu, italian-citizens

I'm an EEA citizen (Italian) currently living in the UK and married to a non-EEA member (Ghanian) and we have a one-year-old son..

1. I want them to join me here in the UK. How do I go about that?
2. Do my wife and son apply togetheror separately?
3. My wife is financially dependent on me. Do I write a letter explaining that, since my wife in unemployed?
4. Do I need to write an invitation letter?
5. The plan is for them to settle with me in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Your son is very likely an Italian citizen also, in which case he should apply for an Italian passport rather than an EEA family permit.  However, the answers below assume that he is not an Italian citizen.

1. Apply for [EEA family permits](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).
2. You will need to submit two applications.
3. There is no need.  The only requirement is that you be a qualified person (for example, employed).  There are no financial criteria.
4. No.
5. There is no question here.

Once again, most children of Italian citizens are automatically Italian from birth, even if only one parent is Italian and even if the child was born outside Italy.  If your son is an Italian citizen, he should get an Italian passport instead of an EEA family permit.

Comment: If the OP was married to his wife for 1.5 years, then his wife is eligible for Italian citizenship as well.