# Visa application for non EEA members

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, eu, family

I am applying for an EEA family permit with my one-year-old son to the UK, so we can relocate and settle with my husband.

How do I fill my son's form since he is one year old? Because the question's on employment, income and expenditure and sponsor details. Thanks

Comment: Is your husband your son's father?  If so, your son likely has his nationality, and, if he does, he does not need an EEA family permit.  This depends on your husband's nationality, though; what is it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your son [is an Italian citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13845/2440) and therefore does not require an EEA family permit.  However, it is still possible to answer this question.

For questions on employment, income, and expenses, you can write "not applicable" or "does not apply."  These questions are actually irrelevant to the EEA family permit generally, but they are all the more irrelevant for someone who is one year old.

For questions about the sponsor, you should answer with reference to your husband.  In the context of an EEA family permit, the term "sponsor" denotes the EEA national from whom the applicant derives the right of free movement.  In this case, it is your husband.